# Proving $\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0$...

Tags: analysis, limits

My goal is to show that $$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{N + 1} \left( \frac{\ \sin{\frac{N+1}{2}(x-t)}}{\sin{\frac{1}{2}t}} \right) = 0$$

I know the limit of the $\frac{1}{N+1}$ part goes to zero, but I'm having a hard time showing that the whole thing goes to zero. I think I want to show that the trigonometric part of the product grows slower than the $\frac{1}{N+1}$ part.

The reason I'm having a hard time doing this is because of the $x$ and $t$ there. I can make the denominator arbitrarily small (meaning I can make the whole thing get arbitrarily large). Then, what determines boundedness (or, at least, slow-growth) would be the numerator. Its dependence on $t$ must be such that, that part of the product behaves well enough for $\frac{1}{N+1}$ to overtake it.

I'm at a total loss as to how to do this (in that case, the $x$ is what's really throwing me off).

Comment: You gave no information about $x$ or $t$. Are they constant? If so, then the part in the parenthesis is bounded and the convergence is clear.

Comment: The $x,t$ are just constants for the purposes of the limit. The term in parentheses is bounded by ${1 \over \sin {t \over 2}}$ for $t \neq 0$, so the limit is straightforward. If $t=0$, the expression is not defined.

Comment: @copper.hat ... yup. God damnit—I've spent so long thinking about this, and what kept tripping me up was, at every turn, I would just make $x$ and $t$ big/small enough to foil a given statement.

Comment: @copper.hat Actually for $t\notin 2\pi\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @AlexR: Indeed, for $t \notin \pi \mathbb{Z}$ :-).

Comment: @copper.hat What's wrong with $\sin(\frac\pi2) = 1$?

Comment: @AlexR: Oops, forgot about the ${1 \over 2}$!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $x,t$ are considered constants within the limits, you have the following limit:
$$L = \lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{1}{N+1} (\frac{\sin((N+1)\omega)}{A})$$
Where $\omega = \frac12 (x-t)$, and $A = \sin(t/2)$

We know that $-1\leq \sin((N+1)\omega) \leq1$, so
$$0 = \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{-1}{A(N+1)} \leq L \leq \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{A(N+1)} = 0$$

You just need to exclude the points when $A = 0$

Comment: ... wich are precisely the points $t\in2\pi\mathbb Z$ i.e. $t = 2\pi k$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$.